# How to notify Gnome users of system reboot/shutdown?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

I am looking for Gnome alternative to KDE write daemon. My goal is to notify Gnome users of coming system reboot or shutdown on the localhost. If the user is logged in KDE and I issue `shutdown -r +5` via SSH, the user gets notified by the respective KDE daemon. However, the Gnome user is left in the dark. The only way for the Gnome user to find out of upcoming shutdown is to open a Terminal. I looked at few options, including `gxmessage` and `notify-send` and they are **not** what I need. The KDE write daemon pops up on certain time periods, while `notify-send` is one time notification, unless I run it in a loop or so.

OS: Ubuntu Linux 10.04, 64-bit, has both Gnome and KDE.

Is there any such notification tool in Gnome?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this question][1]. It's solution for yours... (I cannot comment yet)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696644/linux-shutdown-with-dbus-send

Comment: Thanks, Kamil! This looks interesting, but it isn't what I need as it does not notify logged in Gnome users of incoming shutdown. Any idea how I could achieve this?